# Como resetear un MODAL Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

uds sabran si existira alguna manera de resetear el modal al momento de cerrarlo? tengo un problema que yo tengo 1 imagen que jalo de la base de datos pero cuando cierro y abro de nuevo sigue la misma imagen :(
actualemente encontre esto..

```
$('#modalProducto').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        alert("Producto Cerrado");
    })
```

Pero no me funciono... al "intentar resetear el modal"

UPDATE, cuando presiono la imagen me abre este modal, mostrandome este carrusel utilizando la libreria FOTORAMA.JS, a la primera funciona bien, pero cuando lo cierro y lo abro... ya no se activa la libreria con las 3 imagenes si no que solo muestra 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(document).on("click", ".imgpng", function () {
        $('#modalProducto').modal('show');
       /*$("#fotorama").html("");*/ /*Aca limpio el area donde colocare o armar mi nueva estructura JQUERY HTML que esta abajo*/

                var idproducto2 = $(this).data("cod2"); /*Esta data la traigo de la img que estoy seleccionando.*/
                $("<img id =imgproducto>").attr("src", idproducto2).css("border", "2px solid red").appendTo("#fotorama"), /*Aca en esta imagen, coloco el SRC = de la URL que traigo de la base de datos, las otras 2 imagenes son locales.*/
                $("<img id=imgproducto2>").attr("src", "/Content/img/productos/Producto2.jpg").appendTo("#fotorama"),
                $("<a>").attr({ "href": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=C3lWwBslWqg" }).append($("<img id=imgproducto3>").attr("src", "/Content/img/productos/Producto8.jpg")).appendTo("#fotorama")

    })
```

[image]

Si lo cierro y vuelvo a abrir la imagen para que me muestre el modal me lo distorciona y me lo muestra de esta manera, ahora si refresco la pagina vuelve a su normalidad, cierro y abro y se vuelve distorcionar

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega mas detalles al respeto, por ejemplo el html donde esta la imagen, el cuerpo del modal

Comment: @David081 ya actualice mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Y bastaría con vaciar el modal al cerrarlo

```
$("#modalProducto").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $("bs.modal").html("");
});
```

Ahora, si el problema es con una imagen, deberías imitar el problema CON IMAGEN.
Trata de replicar todo cuando quieras preguntar, agrega el modal como tan y el error que se haga visual para el resto de la gente.

Comment: ahorita pongo mas detallado mi problema

Comment: Por favor, si fe fijas, somos 3 personas tratando de ayudar, pero pidiendo lo mismo... mas detalle en el problema, para dar una solución acorde

Comment: ya actualize  brother

Comment: Eso es todo el codigo del modal ?? parece que falta bro

Answer (score 0):

Probaria algo como esto:

```
// cuando se cierre el modal, remueve la imagen
$('#modalProducto').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('img').remove();
});
```

Este código busca todas las imágenes dentro del modal y las elimina, de modo que cuando abras de nuevo el modal, no se mostrará ninguna imagen.

Luego puedes agregar una nueva imagen a todos los elementos img que se encuentran dentro del modal cuando se muestra. También puedes utilizar la función .html() en lugar de .append() si deseas reemplazar todo el contenido HTML del elemento en lugar de agregar contenido adicional.

```
$('#modalProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('img').append('<img src="path/to/new/image.jpg" 
/>');
});
```

Comment: @Ezequien Estevez ahorita intente eso... si lo borra pero cuando quiero abrirlo necesito esas etiques IMG pero con otra data que traigo de la base de datos... lo que quisera es resetear o cerrar, actualizare mi codigo permitime

Comment: Coloque una img de refencia

Comment: @abra manera que cuando lo vuelva a abrir exista algo de add? para poderlo añadir otra vez?

Comment: Sí, puedes utilizar la función .append() de jQuery para agregar contenido a un elemento del DOM cuando se abre un modal. Edito la respuesta para ejemplificar